# Visiting graph edges with independent paths

Tags: graph, graph-theory, traversal

Given a directed graph with multiple start nodes and multiple end nodes, I need to form paths that visit every reachable edge, but I cannot visit any edge (or vertex) more than once during a single pass.  [*This is to electrically test every connection in a network by sending signals from start to end nodes, but I cannot allow paths to short together.*]

Because I cannot re-visit edges during a single pass:

- I can safely ignore the cycles in the graph.
- I know each path I form will block other paths.
- Consequently, I cannot visit every reachable edge in one pass, so multiple passes are necessary.

From context, I know that the minimum number of passes will be the maximum number of edges entering any vertex.  Once I finish a given pass, I am free to re-visit edges that were visited in previous passes, but never-visited edges are the ones that I most want to visit.

I would like to visit "*many*" edges per pass, so that I can reduce total the number of passes, but I do not strictly need to minimize the number of passes.

Any suggestions on algorithms to accomplish this?  It sounds a little like the [route inspection problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem), except that my graph is directed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question whether you have one or many start points and one or many end points. For simplicity let me assume "one-to-many" network. Then your requirement (not visit any edge or vertex more then once) means you actually generate a spanning tree of your graph with the given root.

A simple but not 100% solution that comes to mind is the following:

Assign some initial weights to the edges and apply [random spanning tree algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/random_spanning_tree.html). Then decrease the weight (actually, relative probability) of visited edges. It is very likely all edges will be visited.

In the case of "many-to-many" connection you can play with different starting points. If some sources are not connected to some sinks the algorithm would throw an exception. If this is not what you inspect, you can run regular DFS first to collect all reacheable vertices into some set; then you can use this set as a filter to form a boost::filtered_graph.

Comment: There are multiple start nodes and multiple end nodes, and I have updated the question to reflect that.